# Как работает Select

Tags: c#, .net, лямбда-выражение

Мне непонятен фрагмент .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)). Что именно делает .Select и что это за n? Откуда она и какой имеет тип и когда этот тип был присвоен? Простите за, возможно, глупый вопрос, но я не понимаю, а на MSDN не нахожу пояснений внятных. или скажите что изучить чтобы это понять?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace my
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Func(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
        }
    }

    static void Func(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            int[] arr = text.Split(',', ';').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Array.Sort(arr);
                Console.Write(arr[i] + "| ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вводи значения через зяпятую(,) или точку с запятой(;)");
            Func(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: солидарен с Вами. К этому синтасису надо привыкнуть. Поначалу, его понимание требует значительных умственных усилий.

Comment: Метод `Select` в качестве параметра принимает функцию, которая вызывается последовательно с каждым элементом из набора, возвращаемого  `text.Split`. Параметр этой функции здесь назван `n` - находится слева от знака `=>`. То, что находится справа от знака `=>` - значение, возвращаемое этой функцией.

Comment: @Igor так мож ответ оформите?

Comment: @tym32167 действительно :)

Comment: @tym32167 вам забыли сказать, что Select лишь возвращает перечеслитель, но не выполняет никаких операций. Операции будут выполняться только когда начнёте обращаться к элементам, например через foreach. Собственно метод ToArray и создаёт сам массив.

Comment: @John вы, наверное, хотели к автору вопроса обратиться. Я то это все и так знаю :)

Comment: @tym32167 да, попутал) это вообще важный момент, а никто о нем не упомянул.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы используете [лямбда-выражение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). Select, Where, Any и прочие функции LINQ являются [методами расширения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) и применяются к любому типу, который реализует интерфейс [IEnumerable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Вкратце результат `Split` возвращает массив, который используется для итерации методом `Select`, где **n** имеет тип `string` и выступает входным параметром функции. Любую LINQ функцию можно развернуть в обычный foreach.

```
var arr = new List<int>();
foreach (var s in  text.Split(',', ';'))
{
    arr.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
}
```

LINQ расширения существенно сокращают объем кода, который должен написать программист.

Comment: Это абсолютно не критично, но я бы таки поменял `функциями расширения` на `методами расширения`, так как это таки более общепринятый термин (в литературе, сайтах, форумах и документации)

Answer (score 2):

Метод `Select` в качестве параметра принимает функцию, которая вызывается последовательно с каждым элементом из набора, возвращаемого `text.Split`. Параметр этой функции здесь назван `n` - находится слева от знака `=>`. То, что находится справа от знака `=>` - значение, возвращаемое этой функцией. Из этих возвращаемых значений формируется набор, возвращаемый функцией `Select`.

Answer (score 2):

К выше существующим ответам добавлю свою толику. Вы можете написать свой `Select()` примерно так

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> res = "2,4,8;9;5".Split(',', ';')
                                  .MySelect(n => Int32.Parse(n));
    }


}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MySelect<TValue, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TValue> values, Func<TValue, TResult> func)
    {
        foreach (TValue item in values)
        {
            yield return func(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверно теперь у автора возникнет вопрос что за TResult и TValue :)

Comment: @adrug вполне возможно, я написал этот пример для общего расширения кругозора, так сказать.

Comment: @Bulson просто мне нужно было взять строку пользовательского ввода, куда пользователь вводит последовательно числа через запятую или точку с запятой и эта строка должна стать целочисленным массивом со значениями, которые ввел пользователь. Просто для чисел есть более очевидные варианты для работы. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @МаксимДонец что значит "мне нужно"? Вы вообще-то спрашивали что такое Select и как он работает...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov да, все так. я имею ввиду, что я работал с пользовательским вводом, а это не то же самое, что переменные определенные мной, т.к пользователь обычно вводит не то, что нужно и не так как нужно. И работать с введенным с клавиатуры значением нужно внимательнее, отсюда у меня и возник вопрос, откуда n и как работает Split().Select(n => ...) и как пользователь может повлиять на выполнение такой программы. Буду лямбда выражения изучать пока что, чтобы ясность внести. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

.Select применяет функцию из аргументов к каждому элементу коллекции. Это унаследованный метод от Enumerable. Кстати, можно поменять с .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)) на .Select(Convert.ToInt32)